# Feature not implemented asmack , Openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am using Openfire 3.9.3 with aSmack library.
When I connect to my chat server, I keep getting the following logs.
Although I connect to server successfully and can chat with using my application.

```
12-31 14:11:53.049: D/SMACK(4613): 02:11:53 PM RCV  (1101270208): <iq type="get" id="130-6586" from="nearbychat.com" to="1@nearbychat.com/Smack"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"/></iq>

12-31 14:11:53.049: D/SMACK(4613): 02:11:53 PM SENT (1101270208): <iq id="130-6586" to="nearbychat.com" from="1@nearbychat.com/Smack" type="error"><error code="501" type="CANCEL"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

I am using this code for setting xmpp connection

```
private void setXmppConnection() {
        if (this.XMPP_CONNECTION == null) {
            this.CONN_CONFIG = new ConnectionConfiguration(MyGlobals.HOST,
                    MyGlobals.PORT, MyGlobals.SERVICE);
            this.CONN_CONFIG
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
            this.CONN_CONFIG.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
            this.XMPP_CONNECTION = new XMPPConnection(this.CONN_CONFIG);
        }
    }

public void connectToChatServer() {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    XMPP_CONNECTION.connect();
                    openFireUsername = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt(
                            "userID", -1));
                    openFirePassword = sharedPreferences.getString("password",null);
                    Log.d(MyGlobals.TAG, "open fire username"+ openFireUsername);
                    Log.d(MyGlobals.TAG, "open fire password"+ openFirePassword);
                    XMPP_CONNECTION.login(openFireUsername, openFirePassword);
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    XMPP_CONNECTION.sendPacket(presence);
                    connectedToChatServer = true;
                } catch (XMPPException localXMPPException) {
                    localXMPPException.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Error localError) {
                }
                return null;
            }

        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Can anybody tell me why am I getting this log repeatedly?
Will these logs affect my application performance, i.e.: battery consumption?
What should I do to get rid of these logs?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void registerXmppProviders(){
        ProviderManager providerManager = ProviderManager.getInstance();
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());
        ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
        ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
        ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
        // Time
        try {
            providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time",
                    Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("TestClient",
                    "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
        }
        //Pings
        providerManager.addIQProvider("ping","urn:xmpp:ping",new PingProvider());
        // Roster Exchange
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster", new RosterExchangeProvider());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
        // Message Events
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event",
                new MessageEventProvider());
        // Chat State
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("active", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("composing", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("paused", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("inactive", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("gone", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        // XHTML
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im",
                new XHTMLExtensionProvider());
        // Group Chat Invitations
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference",
                new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
        // Service Discovery # Items
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items",
                new DiscoverItemsProvider());
        // Service Discovery # Info
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",
                new DiscoverInfoProvider());
        // Data Forms
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
        // MUC User
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user",
                new MUCUserProvider());
        // MUC Admin
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin",
                new MUCAdminProvider());
        // MUC Owner
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner",
                new MUCOwnerProvider());
        // Delayed Delivery
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay",
                new DelayInformationProvider());
        // Version
        try {
            providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version",
                    Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // Not sure what's happening here.
        }
        // VCard
        providerManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
        // Offline Message Requests
        providerManager.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
                new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
        // Offline Message Indicator
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
                new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
        // Last Activity
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
        // User Search
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
        // SharedGroupsInfo
        providerManager.addIQProvider("sharedgroup", "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup",
                new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());
        // JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("addresses", "http://jabber.org/protocol/address",
                new MultipleAddressesProvider());
        // FileTransfer
        providerManager.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
                new StreamInitiationProvider());
        // Privacy
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("session-expired",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
        //  Offline Message Indicator
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",
                new DiscoverInfoProvider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
        // pm.addExtensionProvider("status ","", new XMLPlayerList());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
}
```

Comment: call this method before creating connection with the xmpp based server.

Comment: This isn't working with smack 4.1.7, providing exception for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to register all the providers using ProviderManager class provided by the library itself before login process.

Hope this works !

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Kumar , sorry for late reply . Can you give some code snippet using ProviderManager ?

Comment: I have uploaded setting the ProviderManager setup snippet in this post above. You can use that instead.